# Javascript loop through several objects and return true if

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

What is the best way of getting javascript/jquery to look through these two objects and return a 'true' if slug contains 'gift_wrap'. Please note Objects within CONTENT can vary.

If TRUE, then my code will do something :)

[image]

Comment: please paste the object.

Comment: please add the object in text form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could iterate over all keys and check if there is any wanted string. If found, break the loop and return `true`. If not found `false` is returned.

Best friends are:

- [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) for getting all property names
- [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) for iterating and check.

```js
function isGift() {
    return Object.keys(cart.contents).some(function (k) {
        return cart.contents[k].slug === 'gift-wrap';
    });
}

var cart = { contents: { '8734918ab768671231': { sku: 'MOB101', slug: 'moby-dick-party-picks' }, '873124918ab7686711': { sku: 'gift', slug: 'gift-wrap' } } }

console.log(isGift());
```